# Python Regex to replace absolute paths in text to relative paths added in quotes

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regex and was trying to solve the below problem.

Input String -  `String that has a path as /Users/MyName/moreofPath/  with additional text`

Output String - `String that has a path as "$relativePath/moreofPath/"  with additional text`

The absolute path in the sentence is to be recognized by

1) where `/Users/MyName` starts

2) where last `/` that comes before any other special character or space ends

This should be replaced by relative path in quotes.
Can someone please help me find correct regex for this.

Comment: I suggest you polish your question a bit, I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: @Deano Could you please check it now.

Comment: Are you sure you really need regular expressions to change the prefix of a string?

Comment: why not just use string replace like `output_string = input_string.replace('/Users/MyName/', '$relativePath/')`  ?

Comment: It is not just the prefix change, but i require to replace the absolute path by relative path (which is to be additionally in quotes)

Comment: @Skycc that would not solve my requirement of the "$relativePath/moreofPath/" being in quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's all Python, I would do something like this:

```
import re

thestring = "String that has a path as /Users/MyName/moreofPath/evenmore/ with additional text"
regex = "(.*?)/Users/MyName/(.*/)"
thestring = re.sub(regex, r'\1"$relativePath/\2"' , thestring)
print (thestring)
```

Output:

```
String that has a path as "$relativePath/moreofPath/evenmore/" with additional text
```

What I'm doing is grabbing the matches in the from the parans and substituting them back in the replacement.  Note that the .* makes it greedy up to the last /

Comment: To add, I'm looking for replacement of absolute path in a large text where the rest of the text is retained ie) "String that has a path as /Users/MyName/moreofPath/ with additional text" is the actual string for which I require the output with its relative path enclosed within quotes. Your updated code gives "./reedy/moreofPath/ with additional text" but the output but i need "String that has a path as "$relativePath/moreofPath/" with additional text" as output (with path in quotes)

Comment: oh I think I get what you mean, let me write that up

Comment: But the solution doesn't work. For input : "String that has a path as /Users/MyName/moreofPath/onemore/twomore/ with additional text" , it gives output as "String that has a path as "$relativePath/moreofPath/"onemore/twomore/ with additional text" . Quotes wrongly placed

Comment: I'll fiddle with the regex

Comment: fiddle complete, check that out

Answer (score 0):

using regex that match any path follow by username as long its not space

```
import re
input_string = "String that has a path as /Users/MyName/moreofPath/ with additional text"
output_string = re.sub(r'/Users/MyName([^\s]*)', r'"$relativePath\1"', input_string)
# 'String that has a path as "$relativePath/moreofPath/" with additional text'
```